# trouble in curl in order to login into a form

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login into a forum by using Curl and the link of forum is

https://www.shaanig.org/login.php?do=login

my code can not log in into forum Because the link goes into homepage after loading

That's why i've loste the login forum

Let me know please , Thanks indeed

```
  function vBulletinLogin($user, $pass)
 {
        $md5Pass = md5($pass);
   $data = "do=login&url=%2Findex.php&vb_login_md5password=$md5Pass&vb_login_username=$user&cookieuser=1";

   $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.shaanig.org/login.php?do=login"); // replace ** with tt
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/codecall_$user.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/codecall_$user.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

   $pos = strpos($store, "Thank you for Logging in");
   if($pos === FALSE) 
  {
           RETURN 0;
   }
   else
   {
           RETURN 1;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your curl option for follow location with this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

It will curl not to follow 3xx header redirects.